# Deleted users profile errors out in Desktop view, but is available on mobile view

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

To test if user deletion propagates on to Channels, we created a new user on Channels and deleted their account on Stack Overflow (user self deletion). However their page was still visible on the list of users, albeit, their name was changed to the original one.

[image]

But clicking on their userprofile returns a 500 "Oops! Something Bad Happened!". Interestingly their profile loads with 0 content on mobile site:

[image]

This is a bit inconsistent.